# MYSQL order by query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

If I have custom post types (`post_type`), and I want to guarantee that anything with the post type of `product` appears before anything else in the search result, how could I achieve this? Preferably by just altering the `order by` part of the query.

Currently I have:

```
 ORDER BY posts.post_type DESC, posts.post_date DESC
```

This works, except another post type of `testimonial` comes before `product` on `DESC`. On `ASC` a different custom post type `articles` comes before `product` but I NEED `product` to come first (with them ordered by `post_date` ), then everything else - also ordered by `post_date`.

The full code:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','search_sort_custom',10,2);
function search_sort_custom( $orderby, $query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if(!is_admin() && is_search()) {
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_type DESC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC";

    }
   return  $orderby;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expressions in an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY posts.post_type='product' DESC,
         posts.post_type DESC,
         posts.post_date DESC
```

If you have more requirements you can do:

```
ORDER BY posts.post_type='product' DESC,
         posts.post_type='testimonial' DESC,
         posts.post_type DESC,
         posts.post_date DESC
```

or use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(posts.post_type,'product, testimonial'), 
         posts.post_type DESC,
         posts.post_date DESC
```

Ideally however I would shift the product types to another table and give each type a priority integer.. that way you can fully control the order without such dramas!

Comment: Thanks, can I do:

post_type='product' DESC,
posts.post_type!='product' DESC,
posts.post_date DESC

Comment: Apologies, you still the old expression to keep the grouping.. see update. The comparison returns 1 or 0 (true/false) so your suggestion is the same as my original.

Comment: Thanks Arth ... So this will return ALL products first ordered by post_date DESC, the everything else (mixed together) ordered by post_date DESC. If so, awesome, as that is what I am after.

Comment: The first one seems to work, though I really don't understand it. If I change the DESC to ASC on the first line, things completely break. What is the purpose of the DESC do on the first two lines? I understand the reason for the last DESC (on post_date).

Comment: The comparison returns 1 or 0 (true/false), on the rows where post_type='product' this will return 1 and have priority with DESC, all other rows will return 0 and come after. The next two lines are your original ordering, so within the products the order will be 'product' DESC (all the same) then by date. The others (not product) will then be ordered by their type DESC and then the date within those type groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just do

```
ORDER BY (
     posts.post_type = 'product' DESC, 
     posts.post_type DESC,
     posts.post_date DESC
)
```